# How to conditionally require a related object property in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, client-side-validation

I have related objects `VehicleAcquisition` and `FleetValue`. I want to make `FleetValue.ConditionId` required if `VehicleAcquisition.RequestType.Label == "Replacement"`.

The following solution using `FluentValidation` works, but it does not perform client-side validation:

ConditionValidator.cs:

```
public class ConditionValidator : AbstractValidator<FleetValue>
{
    public ConditionValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(fleetValue => fleetValue.ConditionId).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Inside Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ConditionValidator>();
```

Inside Controller:

```
private readonly ConditionValidator _conditionValidator;

public FleetValueController(ConditionValidator conditionValidator) : base()
{
    _conditionValidator = conditionValidator;
}

if (vehicleAcquisition.RequestType.Label == "Replacement")
{
    var validationResult = _conditionValidator.Validate(vm.FleetValue);

    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        WarningAlert("Please select the condition.");

        return View($"{ViewBase}/Form.cshtml", vm);
    }
}
```

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
public class ConditionValidator : AbstractValidator<FleetValue>
{
    public ConditionValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(fleetValue => fleetValue.ConditionId).NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Please select the condition")
            .When(fleetValue => fleetValue.VehicleAcquisition.RequestType.Label == "Replacement");
    }
}

builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ConditionValidator>();

builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();

builder.Services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
```

I did not see any errors.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `using FluentValidation works, but it does not perform client-side validation` means It works in `Modelstate.isvalid`  but you wanna achieve that when you submit the from , It show the error message directly instead of submitting the from?

Comment: When I submit the form, it first performs client-side validation for the other fields. After I resolve any validation issues for the other fields, such as required values, it then performs validation for the ConditionId, since it performs server-side validation. I would like the validation to be done on all fields, including ConditionId, at the same time. I have to click Submit a second time to see the validation issue for ConditionId.